# добавить datepicker в url при запросе к api

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api

пытаюсь по api получить календарь (ссылка + дата), на сегодняшнюю дату все работает, но сколько по календарю не кликай, изменений (за исключением адресной строки нет), как добавить datepicker в адрес api?

html

```
<body>
  <h1>тут Календарь</h1>
<div id="ap_calendar"></div>
<div id="pageCalendar"></div>

  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="/datepicker/datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/datepicker/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="ap.js"></script>
    
</body>
```

.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log( 'Today: ' + today);
        
    isset_calendar = $("#ap_calendar").length;
    
    if (isset_calendar > 0 ) {
        $( function() {
            $("#ap_calendar").datepicker({ 
                    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy', 
                    minDate: new Date(1900, 0, 1),
                    maxDate: new Date(2099, 11, 31),
                    onSelect: function (fd, date) {             
                        objDate = date.getDate();
                        formatDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        console.log(formatDate);
                        ajaxRequestForPage();
                    },
                });
                
                var active_date = $('#ap_calendar').datepicker().data('datepicker');
                active_date.selectDate( new Date(today) );
        });
    }
        var $dcPageWrap = $('#pageCalendar');

        function ajaxRequestForPage() {
            
            $dcPageWrap.animate({opacity: 0.1}, 300);
    
            jQuery.get(
                "ap.php",
                {
                    date: formatDate,
                },
                function (response) {
                    $dcPageWrap
                        .html(response)
                        .animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
                    history.pushState({}, '', '?date=' + formatDate);
                }
            );
        }
        
});
```

и php

```
<?php
$date=date("Y/m/d");
$url = 'http://api.calendar.drevle.com/' . $date . '';
$num = file_get_contents($url);
$cart = json_decode( $num );
echo $cart->day->dayOfWeek . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->julianDate . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->tone . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->saints . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->fast . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->bows . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->date . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->gregorianDate . "<br>";
echo $cart->day->dailyFeast . "<br>";
echo $date . "<br>";
echo $url . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в файл php меняем значение на:

```
$date = urldecode ($_GET['date']);
```

и "voilà" - ура заработало!